# GStreamer: RTMP to RTP

Tags: streaming, rtmp, rtp

I want to streaming RTMP signal to RTP(multicast, mpegts container) via GStreamer. As I understand, I need to perform the following actions (please correct me if I wrong):

1. Demuxing RTMP stream
2. Muxing tracks to MPEGTS
3. Streaming data into RTP

I can perform it via FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:bigbuckbunny_750.mp4 \
       -c copy -f rtp_mpegts rtp://127.0.0.1:10001
```

I need to achive the same results via GStreamer and I've tried the next command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtmpsrc \
           location=rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:bigbuckbunny_750.mp4 \
           ! flvdemux ! h264parse ! rtph264pay \
           ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=10001

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = "NULL"
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Please help figure out with. **What is the correct command to streaming RTMP to RTP without transcoding via GStreamer?**

Comment: If anyone runs across this, the pipeline in the OP is correct but you can further debug this with the `GST_DEBUG=3` env variable.